# retrieving multiple columns from table using redbeanphp

Tags: mysql, redbean

I have a query which retrieves 3 columns from table which works fine in phpmyadmin

```
SELECT cab_id,
SUM(IF(rating=1,1,0)) as up,
SUM(IF(rating=0,1,0)) as down
FROM rating WHERE cab_id=101
```

table->'rating'
Can anyone help me to find how I can get this query worked using redbeanphp ?
I tried ,

```
 R::getRow(),R::getAll(),R::$adapter->getAssoc()
```

none is working!!!
To check the correctness of code I tried,

```
  SELECT * FROM rating group by cab_id having cab_id=101
```

and found working.But I need the first query statement to work! Any help ,please?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer finally, This one works.

```
 $val  = R::getAll($query);
```